# Howto aggregate on full data set in Spring Batch jobs?

Tags: aggregate-functions, spring-batch

I need to insert aggregation in my Spring Batch jobs.
But the aggregation step need to have the entire data set available.

In pure SQL, it's easy to code SQL aggregation requests : the full data set (as stored in database) is available.

But in Spring Batch jobs, everything is done in memory, and spread in chunked.
So howto deal with that kind of data strewing ?

Do you have any advice concerning the best practices to insert aggregation steps/processes ?

Thx a lot for your enlightments

Answer (score 8):

You have [Partitioning](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/scalability.html) option in spring batch which can have `StepExecutionAggregator`, it has aggregate method which accepts list of `StepContext` of all partitioned steps.

We had i.e. integration with soap server where we first received list of something that needs to be processed, than we partitioned it to child steps and processed in parallel and after each child step finishes aggregator is invoked which can do stuff based on data in child step context.

It is good way if you have something in your data which can be good rule for partitioning (i.e. pull list of items from DB and process each item in parallel, save item data in step context, use aggregator and combine everything in each step context and do common operation on combined data).

Here is [link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-partitioning-example/) to example with partitioning (there is no aggregation but you can add it to `masterStep`).

Comment: I need a single pdf with aggregated data in the end. PDF will contain a transaction type & amount. I can partition by transaction type and run each slave step processing them in parallel i.e read from DB and change the currency to USD. I am confused.  what the writer will do in slave steps? How to aggregate the chunk data in individual slave steps?