# Spring batch - In memory summary of input records before writing the output

Tags: spring-batch

We need to read a large amount of data (a few millions of records), do some business logic on it and write the results **once**.

E.g.

**Input**

Ringo, Elephant, London Zoo

Zooshu, Horse, In the Wild

Domo, Panda, Singapore Farm Animal Sanctuary

Sasha, Elephant, Bombai zoological garden

**Output**

- 2 animals in Asia
- 3 unique species
- 3 animals in captivity
- ...

We are wondering if `Spring Batch` can be a good platform for this because as we understand it, every `ItemReader` flows eventually to an `Item Writer` and we only need to write once.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do aggregation with Spring Batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366710/how-to-do-aggregation-with-spring-batch)

Answer (score 0):

I think Spring Batch is a good fit in this scenario. `ItemReader` will read from the input file and pass every line to a `ItemProcessor`, where your business logic resides. After processing, `ItemWriter` can writer out the result to a file. Go ahead and create a toy with it. https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/